# Why does this code fail? child not waiting

Tags: c++, ubuntu, exec, parent-child, waitpid

Ok so I have been trying to learn to master child processes and properly waiting for them to finish. I have read a lot of Stack Overflow Q/A and I still can't seem to get this to work as I want it to. I have been reading/searching through the book (C++ Primer plus 6th ed.) - I have done some research and still I can't make it wait as I wanted to.

So I have looked at several things here on Stack Overflow for reference: [Checking the status of a child process in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278582/checking-the-status-of-a-child-process-in-c)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
int status;
pid_t child;
child = fork();

if ( child > 0 ) {
    cout << "\nChild #1 is in charge\n";
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
}

else if ( child < 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSomething wen't wrong in the forking process\n";
}

else {

}

child = fork();
if ( child > 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSecond child is in charge\n";
    execlp("locate", "locate", "etc", NULL);
}

else if ( child < 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSomething went wrong in the forking of second child!\n";
}

else {

}
```

Now this would show `Child #1 is in charge` and `Second child is in charge` then it would mix the two commands (I see some `ls` in between locate `etc`).

Second thing I have tried:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
int status;
pid_t child;
pid_t ch_status = waitpid(child, &status, WNOHANG);

child = fork();
if ( child > 0 ) {
    cout << "\nChild is in charge\n";
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
}

else if ( child < 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSomething wen't wrong in the forking process\n";
}

if ( ch_status == 0 ) {

}

else if ( ch_status == -1 ) {
    cout << "\nERROR IN CHILD #1\n";
}

else {

}

child = fork();
if ( child == 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSecond child is in charge\n";
    execlp("locate", "locate", "etc", NULL);
}

else if ( child < 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSomething went wrong in the forking of second child!\n";
}

if ( ch_status == 0 ) {

}

else if ( ch_status == -1 ) {
    cout << "\nERROR IN CHILD #1\n";
}

else {

}

child = fork();
if ( child > 0 ) {
    cout << "\nThird child is in charge!\n";
    execlp("echo", "echo", "herro", NULL);
}

else if ( child < 0 ) {
    cout << "\nForking of third child failed!\n";
}

if ( ch_status == 0 ) {

}

else if ( ch_status == -1 ) {
    cout << "\nERROR IN CHILD #2\n";
}

else {

}

return 0;
}
```

This is more based on the link which I provided, it yielded the same result as the first test run I did, except it would also show `ERROR IN CHILD #1/2`.

The commands are irrelevant, I just wan't to understand what I am doing wrong here... I have also tried nesting them in `else { //start second fork here }`, but I got nowhere with this either.

From what I understand after reading the `waitpid(2)` manual I should be using `WNOHANG`;
http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

Any suggestions/pointers are greatly appreciated.

If possible, please submit a sample code of how you would accomplish the correct result `(execute command 1 -> wait until done -> execute command 2 -> exit)`.

Look forward to replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling `waitpid()` in the parent *after* you fork. That is, it should go into the `child > 0` branch.

The function's purpose is to "wait for a change in the child state." However, you're calling it before you spawn a child.

The code should then look like this:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

int status;
pid_t child;

child = fork();
if ( child == 0 ) {
    cout << "\nChild is in charge" << endl;
    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
} else if ( child < 0 ) {
    cout << "\nSomething wen't wrong in the forking process" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Parent waiting" << endl;
    pid_t ch_status = waitpid(child, &status, WNOHANG);
    if (ch_status == -1) {
      cout << "\nERROR IN CHILD #1" << endl;
    }
}

child = fork();
//same procedure as above

}
```

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you mean, are you at all able to provide me with a small preview of how it should/can look like?

Comment: @dusz I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Will look at it now, second

Comment: Ok so it worked fine this time, however when I ran it as you did with `"\n"` instead of `<< endl` at the end, it was placing content at wrong places. Selecting as answer, consider changing to `<< endl` as @david-schwartz suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly judging the order in which output statements *executed* based on the order their output was *flushed*. While output can't be flushed until the corresponding statement is executed, you have no flush calls in your code. So flushing can happen *much* later.

Use `endl` instead of putting a `\n` at the end of your lines. The `endl` manipulator includes a flush.

Comment: Kudos for pointing that out, however it is still not waiting correctly so I must have done something else wrong. +1