# How to check if a process is running in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, process, pid, rhel6

I have written a program in C++ to read the processes from a file into a vector and then to execute the processes line by line.

I would like to find out which processes are running and which aren't by using proc in c++

Thanks.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int i,j;
    std::string line_;
    std::vector<std::string> process;
    ifstream file_("process.sh");
    if(file_.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(file_,line_))
        {
            process.push_back(line_);
        }
        file_.close();
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"failed to open"<< "\n";
    }
    for (std::vector<string>::const_iterator i = process.begin(); i != process.end(); ++i)
    {
    std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n";
    }

    for (unsigned j=0; j<process.size(); ++j)
    {
    string system=("*process[j]");
    std::string temp;
    temp = process[j];
    std::system(temp.c_str());
    std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no library call that gives you an easy answer to whether or not a process is running. You would need to handle it manually. Something like: call `system("ps aux &> processes.txt")` and the analyse the `processes.txt` file looking for the process name etc.

Comment: You may need to write some code like `ps aux | grep program_name` to see if there exists any instances of `program_name` running.

Comment: @duong_dajgja Yes but I wanted to include that in my code, to know which processes are running.

Comment: @SaurabhJadhav: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes

Comment: Heresy by some since some take the position C and C++ are completely unrelated: [Determine programmatically if a program is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6898337/608639) and [How to find if a process is running in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11785936/608639)

Comment: @duong_dajgja I checked the post, actually I am a learner and I don't know how to use proc in my program.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from http://proswdev.blogspot.jp/2012/02/get-process-id-by-name-in-linux-using-c.html

Before executing your processes pass process name to this function. If getProcIdByName() returns -1 you are free to run process_name. If valid pid is returned, well, do nothing, or kill and run it from your software, depends on your needs.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int getProcIdByName(string procName)
{
    int pid = -1;

    // Open the /proc directory
    DIR *dp = opendir("/proc");
    if (dp != NULL)
    {
        // Enumerate all entries in directory until process found
        struct dirent *dirp;
        while (pid < 0 && (dirp = readdir(dp)))
        {
            // Skip non-numeric entries
            int id = atoi(dirp->d_name);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                // Read contents of virtual /proc/{pid}/cmdline file
                string cmdPath = string("/proc/") + dirp->d_name + "/cmdline";
                ifstream cmdFile(cmdPath.c_str());
                string cmdLine;
                getline(cmdFile, cmdLine);
                if (!cmdLine.empty())
                {
                    // Keep first cmdline item which contains the program path
                    size_t pos = cmdLine.find('\0');
                    if (pos != string::npos)
                        cmdLine = cmdLine.substr(0, pos);
                    // Keep program name only, removing the path
                    pos = cmdLine.rfind('/');
                    if (pos != string::npos)
                        cmdLine = cmdLine.substr(pos + 1);
                    // Compare against requested process name
                    if (procName == cmdLine)
                        pid = id;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dp);

    return pid;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Fancy command line processing skipped for brevity
    int pid = getProcIdByName(argv[1]);
    cout << "pid: " << pid << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well after running the processes I wanted to know which of the initiated processes are running and which failed. @metamorphling

Answer (score 3):

Use `kill(pid, sig)` but check for the `errno` status. If you're running as a different user and you have no access to the process it will fail with **EPERM** but the process is still alive. You should be checking for **ESRCH** which means `No such process`.

If you're running a child process kill will succeed until `waitpid` is called that forces the clean up of any defunct processes as well.

Here's a function that returns true whether the process is still running and handles cleans up defunct processes as well.

```cpp
bool IsProcessAlive(int ProcessId)
{
    // Wait for child process, this should clean up defunct processes
    waitpid(ProcessId, nullptr, WNOHANG);
    // kill failed let's see why..
    if (kill(ProcessId, 0) == -1)
    {
        // First of all kill may fail with EPERM if we run as a different user and we have no access, so let's make sure the errno is ESRCH (Process not found!)
        if (errno != ESRCH)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // If kill didn't fail the process is still running
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't handle recycled pids. can you please show how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

In C, I use [`kill(pid_t pid, int sig)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) to send a blank signal (0) to a specific pid, therefore checking if it's active with the return of this function.

I don't know if you have a similar function in C++ but because you're using linux as well, it might be worth checking [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).